# Using timestamps in rails to send emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, timestamp

I would like to loop over my database and find every item that was placed a certain time period ago (like 5 days ago or 3 days ago) and send an email automatically to the user every time I run the script. So if the user hadn't been activated for 5 days, I want the script to be run daily and check if the time since the user creation has been 5 days or 3 or whatever.

How do I go about doing that in Rails?

Here is what I have so far:

> def send_reminders
>
> ```
> @users = User.where :activated => false
> @message= "Hi"
> @users.each do |n|
>
>    ActMailer.remind_users(n, current_user, @message).deliver
>
> end
>
> redirect_to current_user, :notice => 'Reminders were successfully sent'
> ```
>
> end

Thanks

Comment: Here is what I have so far:

`def send_reminders

    @users = User.where :activated => false
    @message= "Hi"
    @users.each do |n|
      
       ActMailer.remind_users(n, current_user, @message).deliver
       
    end
      
    redirect_to current_user, :notice => 'Reminders were successfully sent'
  end`

Answer (score 1):

Via a little bit of [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) (recommend the when [whenever gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/whenever)), you can run things like this.

You might have something in your user Class like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  REMINDER_TIME_IN_DAYS = 5

  scope :unactivated, where(:active => false)
  scope :unreminded,  where("reminded = ? AND created_at < ?", true, REMINDER_TIME_IN_DAYS.days.ago)

  def self.send_reminders_to_unactivated_users
    User.unactivated.unreminded.each(&:send_activation_reminder)
  end
end
```

And then in the schedule.rb file for whenever:

```
every 1.day, :at => "12:00 am" do
  User.send_reminders_to_unactivated_users
end
```

Comment: How can I instead do this manually without Cron? I will run the function periodically every two days, I just want the function to return the users that were created 5 days ago and are still inactivated..thanks!

Comment: @NosayrYassin read the code carefully. All you need is right there.

Comment: You could just call User.send_reminders_to_unactivated_users manually.

Comment: I'd wrap this up in a rake task to actually make the call but this answer makes sense to me.

Comment: Right, I would wrap it in cron and rake. :D